# Image Resizer: Not accessing private S3 bucket correctly

Tags: image, amazon-s3, imageresizer

We have been creating a Proof of Concept image resizer for our web app, using the current version of Image Resizer (http://imageresizing.net/). 
The prod version will be fronted by CloudFront and an elastic Load Balancer.
The idea, as per documentation is to have the Image Resizer server running and accessing one or more S3 buckets for the media (JPGs) and using Disk Caching to speed up the process.

It is a mandatory requirement the S3 buckets remain private, so we have an IAM account set up - and this account has full access to these buckets - and this has been verified by the AWS Policy Simulator.

With my current IR config the solution only works if I make the images public. It's almost as if the IAM credentials are being ignored.

My resizer config is below, with the IAM access key and secret key altered.

```
<resizer>
    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
    <plugins>
        <add name="DiskCache" />
        <add name="S3Reader2" region="ap-southeast-2" prefix="~/s3" vpp="true" cacheMetadata="true"
            buckets="images-vendorA, images-vendorB"
            accessKeyId="AAABBBCCC" 
            secretAccessKey="123456798" />

    </plugins>
    <diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" />    
</resizer>
```

I acknowledge that we do not have a license for this, but we are in development and not production - and I have not seen any doco on this only being enabled with a license key.

Has any one else encountered any issues with getting Image Resizer to access private S3 content and if so, how did you overcome the issue?

We cant have the image buckets made public as it would violate our contractual obligations from our data providers.

Answer (score 0):

OK. As always, you post on stackoverflow and then the solution presents itself!

My assumption was that due to the Windows error logs that imageresiser was having issues accessing the files - therefore it was permissions / IAM issues.

This is not the case. Closer inspection of the Meta Data revealed the culprit.
The fact that some worked when public was a bit of a false positive - it was just an unlucky break that some worked that way and others didn't.

I'll explain - we used 2 methods to upload our test images into S3. One method was to use the web console and one to use a third party product, CloudBerry S3 explorer Pro. Due to our settings in Cloud Berry, it uploaded our files and gziped them in the process, and added the Content-Encoding: gzip Meta Data.

This was the critical clue that gave it all away. Those uploaded via AWS console were unadulterated so to speak. Image Resizer was not able to read the gzipped files.

Lesson there - watch your metadata and encoding settings when using 3rd party products.

I have no deleted all files in the bucket, removed all public permissions and uploaded them via AWS Console and everything works!

I hope this info helps others in the future.